# generating XLS file with PHP adds blank row at the top of xls file

Tags: php, xls

i have developed reporting system for one website.i have developed script such that my client can export sales data in XLS file with all detail, every thing was working fine, but now i noticed that every generating xls file has blank row at the top,i have not make any change in code, before few days it was not happening. how to remove that blank line from the top

i am using following code to generate xls file:

```
$str = "No\tOrderId\tFirst Name\tLast Name\tOrder Date\tTime\tAddress\tCity\tState\tZip\tCountry\tPhone\tEmail\tProductId\tProductName\tProductQty\t";

        $output = array();
        $output[] = $str;


while($row = $res->fetch())
        {
            $datetime = new DateTime($row['DateTime']);

            $date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
            $time = $datetime->format('H:i:s');

            $Country = getCountryName($row['Country']);

            $stroutput= $cnt."\t".$row['OrderId']."\t".stripslashes($row['FirstName'])."\t".stripslashes($row['LastName'])."\t".$date."\t".$time."\t".$row['Address1']."\t".$row['City']."\t".$row['State']."\t".$row['Zip']."\t".$Country."\t".$row['Phone']."\t".$row['Email']."\t".$row['ProductId']."\t".$row['ProductName']."\t".$row['ProductQty']."\t";



                $output[]=$stroutput;
                $cnt++;
        }
$filename="CustomReport_".$date33."_".$date55."_".date("mdy-His");
        $data = implode("\n", $output);
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".xls;");
        header("Content-Type: application/ms-excel");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        print "$header\n$data";
```

Comment: can you show your code for `$header` .have you tried removing `\n` between header and data like `$header$data`..

Comment: and the code for `$data` :)

Comment: i have used 
$data = implode("\n", $output);
before headers

Comment: check, i have edited code and put code that i am using

Comment: ok guys removing "\n" from print "$header\n$data" solved my issues
thanks for help